# Mocking methods from different class than tested one

Tags: java, unit-testing, mocking, mockito, testng

I have an issue with writing a unit test for one of my methods. It calls a method from a different class and to make it worse it makes some processing depending on a server connection so I would need to mock it somehow however I couldn't find an answer how to do that. I also want to point that tested method does not take this different class object as a parameter but is instantiating it within itself so it looks something like this:

```
public class Class1 {
    public MyEnum method1(String myString){
        Class2 class2 = new Class2();
        return class2.method2(myString);
    }
}
public class Class2 {
    public MyEnum method2(String myString){
       //returns some value after communication with a server
    }
}
```

So basically I would need to mock method2 return value however as it's class is instantiated inside the method1 I can't see a way to do that. Is there any way of testing that without the actual server connection?

Comment: What you want (mocking `Class2`) is not supported in Mockito, at least not yet (it may be in future versions). You would need to use a mocking library which supports the mocking of "future objects", such as PowerMock.

Comment: PowerMock actually did the job, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

As a rule of thumb your unit test should test only one class, everything else should be mocked.
As a rule of good design all dependencies should be injectable, i.e. your Class2 should not be instantiated inside your Class1 (and definitely not inside a method in this class as it creates a fresh instance every time the method is called).
If any of the above rules are broken you should consider rewriting the code.

Comment: Unfortunately I am testing legacy code and I am not allowed to change it unless it actually doesn't work... So if this is testable at all then I need to find a way to do that without refactoring. So is there any feasible way to solve this?

Comment: I am afraid that there is nothing you can do in such situation.

Comment: There's no such "rule of good design" that states dependencies should be injected rather than directly instantiated. On the contrary, all too often stateful dependencies that should be instantiated with client state are deliberately avoided in favor of non-OO stateless "services" which are DI-friendly. I've seen a lot of such DI misuse in real code.